# Why do I receive an empty array after web-scraping with CURL then filtering with regex?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, curl, web-scraping

I'm new to the curl and regex syntax. I tried to get the name of the images in this Amazon page, but I failed.  I don't know why I always get an empty array.

Here is the code :

```
$curl = curl_init(); //$curl is going to be data type curl resource

$search_string = "aser";
$url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=$search_string";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

preg_match_all('!https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/[^\s]*?._AC_US200_.jpg!', $result, $matches);

$images = array_values(array_unique($matches[0]));
print_r($images);

curl_close($curl);
```

This is what I get when I `print_r($images)` :

```
Array ( )
```

Comment: Can you show what `$result` holds?

Comment: how can i  do that please

Comment: `print_r($result)` and let us know what is value in `$result`.

Comment: You are being caught by Amazons re-captcha. If you `echo $result` you'll see the re-captcha displayed.

Comment: oh i get an amazon capcha

Comment: I assume that you should fix your regex, add the result to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've baked in some conditionals to help process unsuccessful outcomes.

Your regex pattern can be tuned up slightly by escaping the dots `\.` and by replacing your negated character class `[^\s]` with `\S` and removing the lazy modifier on the quantifier (`*?` to `*`).  These adjustments will improve pattern brevity, accuracy and performance.

Writing `preg_match_all()` inside of a condition statement is important because it will eliminate the possibility of generating a *Notice* when you try to access/process `$matches`.

I am also changing `array_values(array_unique())` to `array_keys(array_flip())` because `array_unique()` is not famous for its speed.

Code:

```
$search_string = "aser";
$url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=$search_string";

if (!$ch = curl_init()) {
    echo "Failed to generate curl handle";
} else {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, true);
    if (!$result = curl_exec($ch)) {
        echo "CURL error: " , curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        // var_export($result);
        if (!$count = preg_match_all('~https://images-na\.ssl-images-amazon\.com/images/I/\S*\._AC_US200_\.jpg~', $result, $matches)) {
            echo "No matches from CURL result";
        } else {
            $unique_matches = array_keys(array_flip($matches[0]));
            echo "Number of matches (including duplicates): " , $count;
            echo "<br>Number of unique matches: " , sizeof($unique_matches);
            echo "<pre>";
                var_export($unique_matches);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Output (today):

```
Number of matches (including duplicates): 105
Number of unique matches: 51
array (
  0 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/312aWjJbA6L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  1 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41vvgZSuo+L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  2 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51akl1-JppL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  3 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41hY4JMK9DL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  4 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51grWJDfRqL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  5 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/618HsMLxiRL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  6 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Xk7SB4XcL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  7 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41XD8vzETkL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  8 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/515Llv02R-L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  9 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51PShds9wgL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  10 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21A8BB4Rr8L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  11 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41FgGD-l6IL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  12 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51cWC51Cz2L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  13 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41GSAH9C+FL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  14 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41FzWLl4rgL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  15 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ej5-EYX4L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  16 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51cxADccMiL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  17 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51G7mMSXgCL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  18 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51baxIno6CL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  19 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31mPoO28QnL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  20 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pZ4eg6PiL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  21 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51C8rmac8GL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  22 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61dDvHqYFaL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  23 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41sMpLjlXCL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  24 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51iWS9LJFBL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  25 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/115DauVSG3L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  26 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21dMy9USZIL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  27 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Rm4-vT2dL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  28 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51YWdlSwfEL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  29 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51EH7k5FpxL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  30 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41igaez7uIL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  31 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/418QEnTiW7L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  32 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51KHWYGSWKL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  33 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41YSiBizmDL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  34 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41NI6VgawgL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  35 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g86u-lDnL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  36 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Dw7RNztAL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  37 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31yOzULiuJL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  38 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41cwE0JAc7L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  39 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51FczAZusTL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  40 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/5123tSQVLhL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  41 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21qE9DbUPOL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  42 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51bmfezfl6L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  43 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41WlXMEj--L._AC_US200_.jpg',
  44 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61yxq875hwL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  45 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/216na69C7UL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  46 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/316I0rZ2DVL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  47 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31+YG+B0nJL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  48 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41NANHOzveL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  49 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41FPdhl6vlL._AC_US200_.jpg',
  50 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21w5Rqsuc-L._AC_US200_.jpg',
)
```

Comment: thanks, man i wouldn't ask for better, thank you so much for your time

Comment: Please award the green tick to my answer to Accept it.

Answer (score 1):

ok I found out that the $result  return me to a re-captcha page so I added

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE,true) ;
```

thank you guys for the help 
even if i still get an empty array in other sites who don't even use re-captcha

Answer (score 0):

Change your Regex to:

```
preg_match_all('/"https:\/\/images-na\.ssl-images-amazon\.com\/images\/I\/.*_AC_US200_.jpg"/',$result,$matches);
```

Comment: Why would this help? Have you tested it? edit: It doesn't result in parse error, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: I test it against the given amazon query link and i found 35 matches.

Comment: By navigating to the link in a separate page or using the script provided?
OP's expression returns 64 matches, yours 44 for the same HTML source code.